# PHP - how to make page visible only in local network

Tags: php, .htaccess, lan

Hi i've got another question, i'm writing a simple website in PHP and i have problem with visibility of my website in local network to make it visible to remote addresses i used

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDRESS']
```

, but i want to make it visible in my LAN.

How can i do this ??

Comment: Have you tried simply specifying the internal IP addresses?

Comment: Is the server serving the webpages on the same network as your computer you're using to access it? You should make sure it is, and that you don't have it being served on some weird port, like :8888 or something.

Comment: You should do this in the web server or firewall configuration, not in your PHP code.

Comment: How would you want to do this though? Would you want the web server to give you a Forbidden File type of error or would you like the php side to check it so it can display a nicer 'you can't access this internal page' type of error. .htaccess for the first, or include a check in the php file for the second.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

also in .htaccess you can allow from your ip/subnet, like this:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 192.168.1.1/24
```

of course it should match your LAN

Comment: Hi, I kow this question is a bit old but I have an issue. I tried this for my LAN (`192.168.2.1/24`) and it works fine for other computers in the network, but I still get a 403 error when accessing it from the same computer, the server runs on. I also added 127.0.0.1 but it had no effect. Could you help me?

Comment: Try to add:

Allow from localhost
Allow from 127.0.0.1/8

Answer (score 5):

You should be doing this in your .htaccess file.

First you specify a Deny All,
then specify a list of IP addresses that should be allowed.

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from X.X.X.X
allow from X.X.X.X
allow from X.X.X.X
```

You can allow ranges like this:

```
allow from 10.0.0.0-10.255.255.255
allow from 10.0-255.0-255.0-255
allow from 10.*.*.*
```

If you want to allow `1.2.3.254`, `1.2.3.255`, `1.2.4.1`, `1.2.4.2`, `1.2.4.3`, and `1.2.4.4`,
you can do it like this:

```
allow from 1.2.3.254-1.2.4.4
```

Comment: You should also enable at least the `fe80::/64` if any of your clients try to access via IPv6 (it is the future of the internet and should not be bblocked!)

Comment: Apache returns an error using the given code: `order takes one argument, 'allow,deny', 'deny,allow', or 'mutual-failure'`. The second blank in `order deny, allow` must be removed.

Comment: I have now updated the answer to reflect this, thanks @MarcelPfeiffer

Answer (score 2):

The highest voted answer is true for Apache 2.2. If you use 2.4, you have to use something like this:

```
<Limit GET POST>
 Require all denied
 Require ip 192.168.1.0/24
</Limit>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from ::1
allow from 192.168.0.1 etc...
```

The `::1` works great (this is also specified in the windows host file).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure but maybe this is a good enough solution:

```
if( substr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDRESS'], 0, 3) == '10.' ) {
   // welcome...
}
```

Comment: @Vic isn't 10. reserved for printers?

Comment: Of course not! It is a perfectly valid choice of IPs for a local network. See http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1918.html#b

Comment: Yeah, that's because `192.168.0.0/16` is far more common in home configurations. `10.0.0.0/8` is more popular in enterprise because it provides a larger space and hence more flexibility for subnetting.

Comment: We use 24-bit IP blocks where I work :). I know that this is in no way  a perfect solution but works as a quick fix perhaps...

Comment: It should be $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . Pay attention the private IPV4 address ranges are in [10.0.0.0 – 10.255.255.255], [172.16.0.0 – 172.31.255.255], [192.168.0.0 – 192.168.255.255] so you should first check the configuration of your network !